# How to make startup process in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, hdl, intel-fpga

How to make a process that executes only once on powering up?
It is easy to make a process that executes when reset button is pressed, but how to make it run when you plug in the power supply without touching the reset button?
In my example I want to initialize the LCD on startup and I need to send some commands to it in the beginning, but I don't need it in the process that is dependent on some signal like reset(just let's suppose there is no reset button at all).

Comment: Have you tried to declare the signal(s) of your FSM with a default value?

Comment: I don't use FSM way here... at least explicitly.

Comment: You just need a single FF. It's initialized to `1` and cleared to `0` on each clock cycle. When you don't connect a reset to this FF, it will never be `1` again unless you reprogram the FPGA.

Comment: @Paebbels, but where do I check for it? Outside of all processes, i.e. just inside  architecture? I mean.... It would still run on every cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state (first run) is stored in a single FF, which is initialized with '1':

```
signal IsStartup : STD_LOGIC := '1';
```

FF process without reset:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    IsStartup <= '0';
  end if;
end process;
```

Usage example (FSM):

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if (Reset = '1') then
      State <= ST_RESET;
    else
      State <= NextState;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

process(State, IsStartup)
begin
  NextState <= State;

  case State is
    when ST_RESET =>
      if (IsStartup = '1') then
        NextState <= ST_STARTUP;
      else
        NextState <= ST_IDLE;
      end if;
  -- ...
  end case;
end process;
```

Comment: @ScienceSamovar: Usually, you should use this method only for generating a reset automatically at startup, and let all your other initialization logic be triggered by that reset signal.  Remember that power-on reset isn't synchronized to a clock, so the more complicated the logic, the greater risk of violating setup/hold requirements.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question of how to run a process once without having it loop to the top. The OP specifically asks for no sensitivity list. It is fair to say that the question conflates the author's design problem with the specific question of how to get a VHDL process to run only once.

Comment: @RaySalemi I don't know what you read, but not the OPs question ... His problem is not about a process running just once and being deactivated from simulation runs via `wait;`. More over he has a synthesis problem, not a simulation problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a wait statement with no sensativity list.

```
process
begin
   assignment <= "101";
   wait;
end process;
```

That being said, I'd recommend that you instead build this as a state machine.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that if we have no sensitivity list the process will have the "default" sensitivity of clock signal? And will wait statement suspend it forever? Does it have drawbacks on powerconsumption(I mean the waiting inside the chip is implemented somehow I guess).

Comment: yeah, probably to do FSM, seems more logical than suspending the process, I suppose I would need to learn it anyway :)

Comment: sensitivity lists and "wait" statements are only for simulation, not for synthesis

Comment: @maxy, you probably confusing wait with after. And about sensitivity lists... what do you mean? They ARE used for synthesis.

Comment: @ScienceSamovar Nope. See bottom of http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/waits.html ; And sensitivity lists are ignored for synthesis, except to warn you that your simulation may be different from your synthesis because you forgot a signal. (At least that's how I learned it, maybe things have changed.)

Comment: @maxy, how then FPGA knows that it needs to react to changes in signals sensitivity list if they are not synthesized(at least in some way)?

Comment: @ScienceSamovar FPGAs do not wait for signals to change, they are just connecting the wires of logic gates (somewhat over-simplified). Sensitivity lists should never have made it to the VHDL language, IMO; the synthesis tool will figure out if input "wires" are used or not.

Comment: @maxy, oh, now I get it, agree.

Comment: This type of code would be run most often in a testbench rather than in RTL.